# Writing Java interpreter Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

A few days back I wrote a Textinterpreter plugin in Eclipse which basically takes a text file and simply printout it's content in the console. It does this by first taking a text file and converts it to a string.
then it makes an Arraylist out of it from which each line is printed out in the console.

```
    List<String> mLines = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(string)

while(!mLines.isEmpty())) {
String line = mLines.remove(0);
if(line.equals("Stop...")){
                debug(DebugAction.Suspend);
}
System.out.println(">>> " + line + " <<<");

}
```

You can see an if statement in code above which checks whether **"Stop..."** is written on any line in the text file and if it is then the *debug()* funtion is called(which suspends running unless the user press resume() button in debugmode.)

Now I want to do the same for .java files. i.e write a Java interpreter plugin which execute a java file normally until it finds **"Stop..."** written in code.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really want to implement a Java *interpreter*, that'd be a huge project keeping you busy for some years maybe.

The most natural solution for you task might be to scan the Java source file and automatically [create breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel.html&anchor=createLineBreakpoint-org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource-java.lang.String-int-int-int-int-boolean-java.util.Map-) at each Stop statement. Then run the application in debug mode and you get the desired behaviour. Since you only need the line number for creating the breakpoint you can actually keep reading/scanning files line-by-line.
To get additional statements executed (like calling `debug(..)`) [add your snippet as a breakpoint condition](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/IJavaLineBreakpoint.html&anchor=setCondition-java.lang.String-) (followed by `return true;` to tell the debug to stop indeed).

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Herman for your response. Actaully I don't want to use Eclipse Standard Debugger (JDT Debugger). The whole reason I wrote this textinterpreter in first place was because I am developing my own Debugger plugin based on [Platform Debug Model](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug_model.htm) just like JDT debugger but with the above mentioned feature.. While implementing my debugger I needed an Interpreter to interact with, that's why I wrote this very simple TextInterpreter in order to see if my Debugger works or not.

Comment: What I have learned [while writting a Debugger plugin](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html) is that a debugger can only work with an Interpreter that supports debugging. I want my debugger to launch a .java file and treat particular snippets of code like **Stop...** as breakpoints. Later on I would like to add some addtional features to my Debugger aswell. Now my Debugger plugin can for example suspend/resume my Textinterpreter by calling methods such as suspend(), resume() written inside Textinterpreter.java class itself.

Comment: I was wondering if there might be a way to connect my Debug plugin with JDT's  JavaInterpreter inorder to play around with .java files?

Comment: Where did you find any `JavaInterpreter`? For executing Java programs JDT uses the JVM, which precisely speaking, interprets Java .class files, not source code. I'm not aware of the existence of any interpreter that interprets Java source code. If you want to practice writing a debugger, fair enough (but maybe you should choose a **much** simpler language). If you really want to execute Java, use the existing implementation: JVM + JDT/Debug.

Comment: I didn't knew the exact working of JDT. Do you know if there might be a way for my Debugger plugin to communicate with the JVM directly or will that be too complex of a problem? Secondly I am thinking a much simpler solution(if possible) would be if I could develop a Plugin which could somehow extend JDT/Debug functionality to my desire?